# Javascript ContentFlow library, Remove All Items and Add New

Tags: javascript, jquery, coverflow

Hey guys I am using the javascript ContentFlow library found [HERE](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php).

I am loading items with jquery/ajax based on search criteria.

What I need to do is remove all of the old items before loading new items.

This works fine with a small amount of photos( less than 4) but anything more causes long running script errors.

To remove all of the items I am looping and calling the rmItem() function

```
function clearResults() {
    var itemCount = resultFlow.getNumberOfItems();
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        resultFlow.rmItem(0);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a clearItems function to the library. There was no built in functionality to reliably support this.